# What is the story of Devakulya who was transformed into Ganga?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, ganga

Kashyapa and Purnima are the sons of Sage Marichi. Purnima had three children, one of them is Devakulya.

Here is verse from [Srimad Bhagavatham 4.1.14](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/1/14),

> My dear Vidura, of the two sons, Kaśyapa and Pūrṇimā, Pūrṇimā begot three children, namely Viraja, Viśvaga and Devakulyā. **Of these three, Devakulyā was the water which washed the lotus feet of the Personality of Godhead and which later on transformed into the Ganges of the heavenly planets.**

I was wondering how someone's child could be water. I understand this someone is not common person like us but a sage. Still, I want to know:

1. How Devakulya born as water?
2. Why Devakulya was transformed into Ganga?

Comment: I think it means Devakulya was the goddess of that water.

Comment: You should use 'mythology' tag for such questions. 'how someone's child could be water' - the same way Bhishma's mother is a river.

Comment: Devakulya is nothing but an avatar of Ganga. She also took birth in Dwapar yuga as wife of Shantanu and mother of Devrata or Bhishma. Story is already told by you. Not sure what's left in this question.